# How to get rid of the annoying iframe borders?

Tags: html, css, iframe

The fiddle (it's a skeleton of my actual code): http://jsfiddle.net/nkipe/6bhee8c8/
The code:
CSS

```
* 
{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
html
{
    height: 100%;
}
body 
{
    height: 100%;
    background: #FEFFFB;
    font-family: arial, verdana;   
}
#layoutContainer 
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position: fixed;
}

#iframeHeader
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border: 0;
}
#iframeStatusBar
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 15px;
    border: 0;
}
#iframeMainMenu
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
}
#iframeCenterContent
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 65px;
    left: 200px;
    position: fixed;
}
#iframeFooter
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 200px;
    position: fixed;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="layoutContainer">
    <iframe id="iframeHeader" src="#" frameborder="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
    <iframe id="iframeStatusBar" src="#" frameborder="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
    <iframe id="iframeMainMenu" src="#"></iframe>
    <iframe id="iframeCenterContent" src="#"></iframe>
    <iframe id="iframeFooter" src="#"></iframe>            
</div>
```

And when I run my actual code in Chrome, it shows up as grey borders as shown in this image:
[image]

Comment: did you try the solutions you received?

Comment: Of course I tried the solutions. That's why I said existing answers aren't helping.

Comment: Can you give the link of the site? As you can see my snippet is working.

Comment: Had just googled for the same sentence that my question is made of

Comment: If the `frameborder` attribute doesn't do it for you in IE, I have a vague recollection that some versions insisted on `frameBorder` with a capital B.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

just add this to your CSS:

```css
iframe {    
 border: 0;
}
```

See snippet below:

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #FEFFFB;
  font-family: arial, verdana;
}

/*ADD THIS BELOW */
iframe {
  border: 0 ;
}
/*END*/

#layoutContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: fixed;
}
#iframeHeader {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 0;
}
#iframeStatusBar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  border: 0;
}
#iframeMainMenu {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
}
#iframeCenterContent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 65px;
  left: 200px;
  position: fixed;
}
#iframeFooter {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 200px;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div id="layoutContainer">
  <iframe id="iframeHeader" src="#" frameborder="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
  <iframe id="iframeStatusBar" src="#" frameborder="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
  <iframe id="iframeMainMenu" src="#"></iframe>
  <iframe id="iframeCenterContent" src="#"></iframe>
  <iframe id="iframeFooter" src="#"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Apply this code in `css` file `iframe{border:none;}`.

And check below link

http://jsfiddle.net/6bhee8c8/1/

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is with frameBorder="0", I see you had tried this but missed the uppercase 'B'

Comment: `frameborder` is not case sensitive.