# Yellow rectangle partially obscuring AdSense ads on mobile

Tags: css, adsense

On my website, when I show adverts on mobile, I get an odd yellow rectangle obscuring the right-hand side of my Google AdSense:

[image]

That's my own wobbly question mark in the the yellow space, and I've fill-flooded the background to make it stand out more.

I've examined the styles through the Chrome Developer Tools window, but I cannot find anything set to yellow in the style hierarchy, and I'm using mostly the bog-standard `minileven` WordPress-supplied theme. What could be causing this? How can I correct the CSS to get rid of this? Ads look fine on the desktop version, only mobile.

A typical page is [this one](http://whatjapanthinks.com/2017/04/10/japans-most-interesting-university-names/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had another closer look at the problem, and for some reason or other [there is a rule like this](https://gitweb.gentoo.org/proj/blogs-gentoo.git/tree/plugins/jetpack/modules/minileven/theme/pub/minileven/style.css?id=7aea9fc04bd42e2ac02a1925d3a02a76d391c3e7#n239):

```
embed, iframe, object {
    width: auto;
}
```

For some reason that I can't work out, this overrode the explicit `<iframe width="320"`, so by trial and error I found that adding this to my custom CSS:

```
.mobile-theme .adsbygoogle iframe {
    width: inherit;
}
```

Overrode the `width: auto;` and I now no longer get my yellow border. There's still a bit of an ugly yellow border at the link widget at the bottom, but at least that's not obscuring anything, so I'll ignore it for now...

Comment: Hmm good find. If the iframe is showing a border you should be able to get rid of it by adding `border: 0 none;` to your embed, iframe, object call. [See this post here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27942526/how-to-get-rid-of-the-annoying-iframe-borders) IMO it might be worth talking to the Ad company about this. It seems odd that these are showing in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your site and viewing an Ad I do see some extra spacing (the one I viewed is different than the one in your screenshot) 
When I view the DOM this is the code that is causing the extra spacing:

```
<td class="rh000c">
   <div class="rh-box-empty rh000"></div>
</td>
```

Here is the related CSS:

```
.rh000c {
    height: 102px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 2px;
}

.rh000 {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 102px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    width: 2px;
}
```

For some reason the Ad is passing this code into its `iframe` so I don't think there is much you can do to remove it. (Well, there might be ways to remove this code but you might violate your service agreement with the Ad agency if you do)

If I were you I would contact the Ads company you are using (it seems that you are using Google Ads) and ask them about this issue directly. Hope that helps.

Comment: Oh I see. But it seems odd that Google would be consistently serving up bum CSS to me; I can't say I've ever noticed this effect on any other site.